# Mockito verify call before/after a group of others

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, verify

How to verify that one call happens after (or before) a number of other calls, without specifying an order for the others?

E.g.:

```
objA.method1();
objB.method2();
objC.method3();
transaction.commmit();
```

I might want to check that `commit` is called after all those other interactions. But I don't want to constraint them on a specific sequence.

Comment: Hi @Vituel, Have you tried with the answer providedr? Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

Probably there are better options (I'll be waiting for other answers), but one choice is defining three different [`InOrder`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#inOrder(java.lang.Object...)), one per each method call (objA, objB, objC) and transaction, and then verify all InOrder independently.

Something like this (is just an example):

```
class ObjA {
  void method1() {}
}

class ObjB {
  void method2() {}
}

class ObjC {
  void method3() {}
}

class Transacction {
  void commit() {};
}

class ClassToTest {
  private ObjA objA;
  private ObjB objB;
  private ObjC objC;
  Transacction transaction;

  ClassToTest(ObjA objA, ObjB objB, ObjC objC, Transacction transaction) {
     this.objA = objA;
     this.objB = objB;
     this.objC = objC;
     this.transaction = transaction;
  }

  void method() {
     objA.method1();
     objC.method3();
     objB.method2();

     transaction.commit();
  }
}
```

Test method:

```
@Test
public void testMethod() throws Exception {
   ObjA objA = mock(ObjA.class);
   ObjB objB = mock(ObjB.class);
   ObjC objC = mock(ObjC.class);
   Transacction transaction = mock(Transacction.class);

   // Create a InOrder per each call and transaction
   InOrder inOrderObjA = inOrder(objA, transaction);
   InOrder inOrderObjB = inOrder(objB, transaction);
   InOrder inOrderObjC = inOrder(objC, transaction);

   ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest(objA, objB, objC, transaction);
   classToTest.method();

   // Verify transaction.commit() is executed after objA.method1()
   inOrderObjA.verify(objA).method1();
   inOrderObjA.verify(transaction).commit();

   // Verify transaction.commit() is executed after objB.method2()
   inOrderObjB.verify(objB).method2();
   inOrderObjB.verify(transaction).commit();

   // Verify transaction.commit() is executed after objC.method3()
   inOrderObjC.verify(objC).method3();
   inOrderObjC.verify(transaction).commit();
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the answer you are looking for, but sometimes hard to test code means it's time to refactor.  Extract the sequence of three order-independent method calls as a single method `myClass.abcMethods()`, and then using a Spy on your SUT simply do an `InOrder` verify of `myClass.abcMethods()` and then `transaction.commit()`